# Accessing focus state of element in Vue3 setup function

Tags: javascript, dom, vuejs3, ref, onfocus

I am using vue3.

I have a simple auto-complete widget method in the `setup()` of my component.

I want to hide the autocomplete dropdown when a user focuses away from input or makes a selection. To do this I want to check the focus status of my input element, however, Vue3 doesn't seem to like me doing this in a setup function which is technically before the element is mounted. What is the best way to do this?

my component looks something like this:

```
<input ref="postcode_input" ...>
```

```js
  ...
  setup() {
    let searchTerm = ref('')
    ...
    let postcode_input = ref(null) //attempt to access ref element
    ...
    const searchLocalities = computed(() => {
        
        if (searchTerm.value === '') { 
            return []
        }

        let matches = 0
        //would like add a check for postcode_input focus == true here...
        return postcodes.value.filter(locality => {
            if (locality.locality.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.value.toLowerCase()) && matches < 10) {
                matches++
                return locality
            }
        })
    });

    /* selection function to populate form */
    const selectPostcode = (location) => {
        selectedPostcode.value = location.postcode
        searchTerm.value = location.locality
    }
    let selectedPostcode = ref('')

    return {
        searchTerm,
        searchLocalities,
        postcodes,
        selectPostcode,
        selectedPostcode,
    }
```

I've tried wrapping the element status in an `onMounted` method but it still throws an error.

Is there a correct way to do this? I was going to resort to an on change function resetting a global variable but was hoping there was a simple way to check the focus status of an element without resorting to that.

Comment: The only two ways that I know to check if an element is focused is via css with :focus or :focus-within, or by reading the value of document.activeElement() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement

Comment: Sure. The issue is Vue wont let me call that function from inside the setup() as it's before the element is mounted. My method is running throughout the lifecycle... so I assume there must be a way to call out to the DOM once the item has been mounted. That is what i am trying to find out. Or get a suggestion for another way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Your question doesn't include any code where you are attempting this though. Could you post it so we can see what are you trying?

Comment: I don't know how to even access the focus status. I have tried accessing it via the `postcode_input ref` listed in my code but all I get is null or undefined errors.

Comment: Well if you wanted to "access focus state" you would have to do something like this: `postcode_input.value === document.activeElement` this would return true if it was focused and false if it was not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are looking for the [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) or [focus-out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event) events.

```
<input ref="postcode_input" @blur="hidePopup" @input="hidePopup">
```

Comment: that works, but it fires before my selectPostcode event... so now I can't add items from the drop down to my input field. Is there a way to control the order of events in vue to stop the @blur event happening before I update the field?

Comment: Hmm, not directly the browser really decides the order that things happen in event-wise. However you might be bale reorder it with the application of the setTimeout() function in your blur callback. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: Wrapping the hide function in setTimeout worked. Seems like a hacky way to achieve what I wanted